# Why are atoms ionized at ICP-MS temps?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, plasma-physics, ionization-energy

If the upper temperature of an ICP-MS (Inductively Coupled Plasma - Mass Spectrometry) plasma is 10,000 kelvin, why are any atoms introduced ionized?

1 eV is equivalent to 11,605 kelvin and the first ionization of every element is greater then 1 eV.

I am missing something. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 1):

In a gas the velocities of the atoms or molecules in the gas is related to the temperature by the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). The average kinetic energy is around $\tfrac{3}{2}kT$, which as you say is of order $1$eV in this case, but the distribution has a tail that extends to higher velocities/energies. At high velocities the fraction of atoms with those velocities falls off roughly exponentially but at $10000$K there is still a significant fraction of atoms with high enough energies to ionise them in collisions.

Comment: How would you calculate the lowest temp at which the tail is significant for atoms with first inonization energies of ~6 eV?

Comment: @RB44 Simply work out the velocity that has a centre of mass collision energy of around 6eV, then use the Maxwell-Boltzmann formula to work out the fraction of molecules with this energy as a function of temperature. Offhand I don't know what ion concentrations the mass spec needs so I can't do that calculation.

Comment: Thanks John. I'll try and calculate this out by this weekend and get back to you if your are amenable. I need to do some sample method development on the device, but to be honest I would prefer to try to understand how it works intrinsically.